Safari and App Store doesn't work on MacBook Air on wifi
Safari and App store don't work on MacBook Air M1 on my home wifi, but Google Chrome does. Safari and the App Store both work over home ethernet.
I updated macOS (only works with ethernet) to version 14.6.1 and restarted the Mac, but it didn't fix the problem.


You have done good work to identify that one of your networks has limited access to the internet.
Keep using chrome (or another browser) to check things as you make changes to the “broken” network. Also, keep using the Ethernet network to convince yourself the Mac settings and OS are working just fine and it’s something on the settings for that one network that is problematic.
Before you do a deep dive, document the DNS settings for both networks. Consider using OpenDNS or another neutral DNS to make sure it’s not just name resolution issues.
Then you will need to examine which hosts and which ports need to be open for Safari and Mac apps like the App Store to work.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/101555


Apple products require access to the internet hosts in this article for a variety of services. Here's how your devices connect to hosts and work with proxies:
Network connections to the hosts below are initiated by the device, not by hosts operated by Apple.
Apple services will fail any connection that uses HTTPS Interception (SSL Inspection). If the HTTPS traffic traverses a web proxy, disable HTTPS Interception for the hosts listed in this article.

Since there are a lot of items in the enterprise networking requirements, focus on the section Apps and additional content as well as HTTPS and TLS errors. You may need to enable the Safari developer tools if you can’t manage the wireless network and look at the network logs and network router configuration.
